# Using LINQ query on Dictionary and List 

Tags: linq

I have  a  `Dictionary<int, int> idsAndTypes = new Dictionary<int, int>();` and i have a

```
List<Product> products = new List<Product>()
```

as list of products , the product class is as below

```
class Product
{
public int Id {get;set;}
public int Type{get;set;}

}
```

the dictionary idsAndTypes contains id's and types , now i want to use a linq query on the list to update the type of products based on id's in the dictionary....
i know the other way can be like following :

```
foreach (int item in idsAndTypes.Keys)
{
    Product.Where(product => product.Id == item).
      Select(product => product).ToList()[0].
      Type = idsAndTypes[item];
}
```

but i want to do it with a linq query to avoid the `foreach` loop, is there a way to do it ?
Please suggest...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, LINQ is really for *querying* not for *updating*.

There may be a way of doing it without the loop, but I think the loop is the cleanest way. However, I wouldn't use that loop. You've got something which is very quick to look up, and you're just iterating through it... but then doing a lookup (effectively) on a *slow* data structure in terms of lookup. I'd do this:

```
foreach (Product p in products)
{
    int type;
    if (idsAndTypes.TryGetValue(product.Id, out type))
    {
        p.LinkedProductType = type;
    }
}
```

One difference here - that will update *all* the products in the list with values in the dictionary; your current code will only do the *first* product in the list with the given ID. I hope that isn't a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your sample code is quite confusing. But I think what you want is:

```
products = products.Select(p => 
  { 
    p.LinkedProductType = idAndTypes[p.ID]; 
    return p;
  }
);
```

While this should achieve the goal, I would considered it an abuse of LINQ.